# Binding a model to a backbone client template

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following backbone.js client side template:

```
<script id="calleeTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
<tr style="background-color: ${StatusColour}">
    <td class="responder">${ContactFullName}</td>
    <td class="status" style="width:200px">${Status}</td>
    <td class="replied">${Replied}</td>
    <td class="wauto">${Response}</td>
</tr>
</script>
```

In order to be able to bind to these properties, I have the following render method of a view:

```
App.Views.Callees = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function () {

  },
  el: $('#calleesStatuses'),
  render: function () {
    var col = _.map(this.collection.models, function (item) {
        return item.attributes;
    });

    $('#calleesStatuses').html('');
    $('#calleeTemplate').tmpl(col).appendTo(this.el);
  }
});
```

I have to extract the attributes using the underscore `_.map` function from the model. I think the reason for this is because backbone uses the `.get("property")` to extract the property value.

This does not seem right to me, am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, you have to transform the data in order to be able to easily use it with tmpl.

However, it's better practice to use `toJSON` rather than accessing attributes directly. It's probably best to avoid calling the `.models` directly as well.

You don't need to anyway, backbone collections have a full suite of underscore.js enumerators. So you can cut your transformation down to one line:

```
var col = this.collection.invoke('toJSON')
```